# Unable to re-size HTML textarea element when CodeMirror modules are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `textarea` in the my `HTML`. For the element, i'm using `codemirror.js` and `codemirror.css` modules(of [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/)).

```
<md-content flex style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;">
    <textarea id="textArea" style="flex:1"></textarea>
</md-content>
```

I use separate JavaScript file to manipulate the modules.

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('textArea');
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
  lineNumbers: true
});
```

When I open this in the browser text area is automatically filled horizontally in the window but not vertically (width:100% & height:50%).
I tried adding `<style>` and setting the width and height. But it changes nothing.

```
<textarea id="textArea" style="flex:1; width:200px; height:300px"></textarea>
```

Also,I tried change CSS using JavaScript, again, it didn't change the size of the element.

```
textArea.style.width = 200;
textArea.style.height = 300;
```

I wanted that `<textarea>` to be filled within `<md-content>`, that's why I have used `flex:1`. How can i change the size to fill the parent tag's area (same size as the parent `md-content`).

This is the [complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/e86pztkh/)

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: how can i add one?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Roysh please find the jsfiddle in the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/e86pztkh/)

Comment: and is this what you want to get? - https://jsfiddle.net/g80caa61/

Comment: Because I'm creating a code editor I want to use CodeMirror js and css modules. But after i use them, the size can not be changed.

Comment: https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css You aren't addressing the right class. .CodeMirror in the CodeMirror css

Comment: Nope. I'm using the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/e86pztkh/1/

```
.CodeMirror {
  position: relative !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
html, body{ 
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
```

}

Not sure if you have the codemirror css file locally, if you do just modify it and dump the !important declarations.